# C# Json File Add New Value

Tags: c#, json

Example:

```
"database": {
  "UUIDTOKEN": {
    "name": "test",
    "yearsold": "20",
    "userid": "100",
    "uuid": "a2b45475-aebe-4103-9c01-43ea8754dfc0",
    "email": "email@gmail.com"
  }
},
```

How to add new value ? so, database = main json text. How to add uuid {
  name,yearsold,userid,uuid,email
}

```
"database": {
  "UUIDTOKEN": {
    "name": "test",
    "yearsold": "20",
    "userid": "100",
    "uuid": "a2b45475-aebe-4103-9c01-43ea8754dfc0",
    "email": "email@gmail.com"
  },
  "UUIDTOKEN": {
    "name": "stackoverflow",
    "yearsold": "24",
    "userid": "110",
    "uuid": "uuid-aebe-4103-9c01-43ea8754dfc0",
    "email": "stackoverflow@gmail.com"
  },
},
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

An object (the `"database"` in your case) can't have two fields with the same name (`"UUIDTOKEN"`). If you need your `"database"` to contain a list of `"UUIDTOKEN"` objects, consider changing it to an array:

```
{
    "database": [{
        "name": "test",
        "yearsold": "20",
        "userid": "100",
        "uuid": "a2b45475-aebe-4103-9c01-43ea8754dfc0",
        "email": "email@gmail.com"
    }, {
        "name": "stackoverflow",
        "yearsold": "24",
        "userid": "110",
        "uuid": "uuid-aebe-4103-9c01-43ea8754dfc0",
        "email": "stackoverflow@gmail.com"
    }]
}
```

Please note, the `"UUIDTOKEN"` name was eliminated in this sample, but if you need it for some reason, add another object layer:

```
{
    "database": [{
        "UUIDTOKEN": {
            "name": "test"
            //...
        }
    }, {
        "UUIDTOKEN": {
            "name": "stackoverflow"
            //...
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking? Do you want to know how to add another value to a json object in c#, or do you want to know why what you've written won't work?

If it's the latter, you can't have a json object with 2 keys the same, you will need to change UUIDTOKEN to a unique key. Otherwise you could use an array.